# After installing ubuntu,the internal disk drives are read only

Tags: hard-drive

After dual boot of ubuntu with windows 10, the internal drives within PC are read only.How to change it to normal mode because I cannot change any thing to my files?

Comment: According to this https://www.howtogeek.com/236807/how-to-mount-your-windows-10-or-8-system-drive-on-linux/ Windows 10 can do a 'hybrid boot' (aka fast boot) which prevents Ubuntu from accessing the drive properly. Can you confirm wether it works if you 'Restart' from within Windows, rather than using shutdown?

Comment: Restart is not helping.I even reinstalled ubuntu but still while I try to change any thing, it says the drive is read only.

Comment: How did you mount the drives? Please edit your question to include the contents of `\etc\fstab`

Comment: And which drives are read-only? The Windows partitions, or linux, or other/data?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both windows should not be hibernated. Like if windows 10 is hibernated I also cant access drives via Ubuntu in dual OS system. It is actually a good feature in Ubuntu. Eg. When we transfer or delete something in drives while using windows, it updates those all information on HD tables  at the time of shut down. So until windows does not save changes, those modifications can not be visible in other OS. I came to know about this when I was using XP with windows 7 as dual OS system, at that time I was facing this issue. Since I started using Ubuntu I never faced this issue. You can say it is properly managed for dual booting.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The problem has now been solved.Actually even after a reinstall the problem was still existing but comments by some of you guyes about windows fast boot saved my day. I restarted windows and selected ubuntu to open from the boot menu and the problem was gone.Now I can change my files and folders like before.Thank you guyes :)